# Faster code for solving an equation with parameters

Tags: performance-tuning

I am new to *Mathematica* and wanted to solve an equation that depends on parameters. The code is below

```
    theta = 0.3;
    v = 0.05;
    alpha = 1;

    q := InverseCDF[ GammaDistribution[ alpha, 1], (1 - theta)]
    rk[k_, r_] := r k
    rkplus1[k_, r_] := r k + 1

    Lfun[k_, r_] := 
      (1/rkplus1[k, r])^alpha Exp[ rk[k,r] q] CDF[ GammaDistribution[ alpha, 
                                                                     1/(rk[k, r] +1)],
                                                   q]

    Lplustheta[k_, r_] := theta + Lfun[k, r]
    logLplustheta[k_, r_] := Log[ Lplustheta[k, r]]
    LHS[k_, r_] := rk[k, r] q Lfun[k, r]/Lplustheta[k, r] - logLplustheta[k, r  ]
    RHS[r_] := r v
    r := 1;

   While[ r < 100,
         { While[ LHS[ k 0.00001, r 0.05] < RHS[r 0.05], a = k 0.00001; k++], 
           Print[ r 0.05, " ", v, " ", theta, " ",
                  Lfun[k 0.00001, r 0.05], " ", a, " ", 
                  a/Lplustheta[ k 0.00001, r 0.05], " ", 
                  a - (a/Lplustheta[k 0.00001, r 0.05])]; k := 1}; r++]
```

The code works but is extremely slow. Is there a faster way to accomplish what I trying to do?
Essentially solve `RHS - LHS == 0` for `k`, for a range of `r`, and print?

Comment: To quick things. 1) Don't use `SetDelayed` ( := ) to compute `q`, use `Set` instead. `q` is a constant and doesn't need to evaluated over and over again as you iterate through your loop. Define it once and for all with `q = InverseCDF[GammaDistribution[alpha, 1], (1 - theta)]`. 2) Don't write slow procedural code to solve your equation. Use one of _Mathematica_'s built-in solvers to do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your inner while loop that is causing the trouble. I refactored your code a bit also. Basically your value of `k` decreases after the first run. So you only have to do this whole run (over `k`) once. This is much faster:

```
θ = 0.3;
v = 0.05;
α = 1;
r = 1;
k = 1;
q = InverseCDF[GammaDistribution[α, 1], 1 - θ];
Lfun[kr_] := 
 Exp[kr q]/(kr + 1)^α CDF[
   GammaDistribution[α, 1/(kr + 1)], q]
LHS[kr_] := 
 Block[{Z = Lfun@kr}, (kr*q*Z)/(θ + Z) - Log[θ + Z]]
While[r < 100, 
 If[1 == r, While[LHS[k*0.00001*r*0.05] < v*r*0.05, k++];, 
  While[LHS[k*0.00001*r*0.05] > v*r*0.05, --k];
  ++k;];
 a = (k - 1)*0.00001;
 σ = Lfun[k*0.00001*r*0.05];
 Print[r*0.05, " ", v, " ", θ, " ", σ, " ", a, " ", 
  a/(θ + σ), " ", a - (a/(θ + σ))];
 r++]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works beautifully.